# Event-driven management of tkinter Combobox selection with ComboboxSelected

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox, binding

My first question, I hope it is formed reasonably. I am writing a Python tkinter GUI that will chart different kinds of data as requested in a ComboBox.  A user will select an entry, and the mapplotlib chart will update. I am a long-time programmer, but still learning basic Python and object-oriented approaches.

I fear I don't understand some basics.  I've got the Combobox bound to a function and it works fine, but many of the examples on the Web include just an "I am here." print statement in that function.  But a choice in the combobox will affect several things.  I must have the logic wrong; I can't figure out how to format a lambda function call to pass the chart and widgets and such to the callback function. But moreover, I can't imagine burying main program logic in a callback function.  But if I do something simple in the callback function, like storing the choice in a variable, I then need to get the program to take action outside of the Combobox selection even, which seems counter to an event-driven style.

The combobox works, and I can print the selection.  I have considered repeated calls to time.sleep() or the like to sense a changing variable, but that seems bad form. I've tried passing a class to callback, but don't know the format.  I have experimented with combobox.after, but that doesn't seem appropriate.

```py
from assign_choices import WidgetChoices

def make_chart_page(nb, chartPage, wc, product_choice):
    comboValues = []                                        
    # Get names for entry into Combobox.  This will depend upon the product.
    Get_Combo_Entries(wc)
    for i in range(len(wc.varList)):
        comboValues.append(wc.varList[i][0])
    # Add the chooser
    comboChart = ttk.Combobox(labelFrameChart, values=comboValues, width=25)
    comboChart.pack(anchor="w", padx=5)
    comboChart.current(0)
#    comboChart.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", callback)
#    data={"one": 1, "two": 2}
    data = wc 
    comboChart.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda event, arg=data: callback(event, arg))

def callback(eventObject, arg):
    a_c = eventObject.widget.get()
    print("ACTIVE CHART      " + a_c)
    arg.active_chart = a_c


class WidgetChoices():
    def __init__(self):
        self.active_product = "POTATOES"
        self.active_chart = "Producers"
        self.active_map = "POTATOES"
        self.varList = []
```

This code is mid-flail, I don't think addressing a specific error would be helpful.  Instead, how do I either: 1) store the Combobox choice in class wc, and then ask the main routine to update the chart, or 2) if necessary, pass everything needed to the callback function and have it update the chart?

Thank you for your help,
Randy

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance I am clear on this now, with some more learning and help from H. Yik in response to another question.  The following passes arguments successfully, and updates an attribute of the chart within a module, as needed.  The following is stand-alone but captures the solution.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg,
                                               NavigationToolbar2TkAgg)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

def make_chart_page(nb, chartPage):
    global canvas
    labelFrameChart = tk.LabelFrame(chartPage, text="Chart control:")
    labelFrameChart.pack(side="left", fill="y", padx=5, pady=5)
    comboChart = ttk.Combobox(labelFrameChart, values=["Foos", "Bars", "Widgets"], width=25)
    comboChart.pack(anchor="w", padx=5)
    f = Figure(figsize=(7,5), dpi=100)
    a = f.add_subplot(111)
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, chartPage)
    canvas.show()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    data = [ "ZERO", a ]
    comboChart.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda event, args=data: callback(event, args))

    tester(a)

def tester(a):
    a.set_xlabel("XAXIS RESET BY TESTER")

def Update_Chart(combo, var0, chart):
    print ("Combobox choice is: ", combo)
    print ("Args[0] is: ", var0)
    chart.set_xlabel("Xaxis reset by Update_Chart")
    canvas.draw()

def callback(eventObject, args):
    Update_Chart(eventObject.widget.get(), args[0], args[1])

def demo():
    root = tk.Tk()
    nb = ttk.Notebook(root)
    chartPage = ttk.Frame(nb)

    make_chart_page(nb, chartPage)

    nb.add(chartPage, text='Charts')
    nb.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    demo()
```